# JUI Autocomplete html-encoded suggestions

Tags: yii, jquery-ui-autocomplete, html-encode

jQuery UI starting from version 1.8.4 html-encodes Autocomplete suggestions (according to [this issue](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5275)).

This became a problem for me now. I used to theme the output for the suggestions, but now (if I use version 1.8.4 or higher) Autocomplete just html-encodes my theming. All tags like `<b>`, `<span>` are being printed to the user instead of displaying the actual styling.

So the suggestions now look like:

- `<b>`su`<b>`suggestion
- another `<b>`su`<b>`suggestion

instead of:

- **su**ggestion
- another **su**ggesion

I've read about custom data, but I use Yii framework and the output is being generated from certain actions (PHP code).

So, how do I theme the output now?

Thank you!

Comment: This is a duplicate question, sorry. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488016/using-html-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

You can use `open` function from jQuery UI to replace the encoded text.

Here's an example:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
                'name'=>"bug",
                'source'=>$this->createUrl('/autocomplete'),

                // additional javascript options for the autocomplete plugin

            'options'=>array(                       
                    'open'=> 'js:function(event, ui){
                      $("ul.ui-autocomplete li a").each(function(){
                      var htmlString = $(this).html().replace(/&lt;/g, "<");
                      htmlString = htmlString.replace(/&gt;/g, ">");
                      $(this).html(htmlString);
                      });
                    }'
            ),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use a [HTML plugin](https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/master/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.html.js)