# jQuery UI autosuggest search box with results presented in similar format to linkedin's search

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete, autosuggest

I'm trying to create an autosuggest search box using jQuery UI and I would like it if I could present the results similarly to how linked-in presents theirs within groups (screenshot attached). Does anyone know how this might be accomplished?[image]

Comment: You use _`renderItem`. It's been asked a lot on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488016/using-html-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435964/jqueryui-how-can-i-custom-format-the-autocomplete-plug-in-results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example [here](http://public.blackpearl.minus3.nl/autocompleter/demo/table.html) which may help.

Comment: Any other place where I might access the example? The link seems broken.