# Jquery UI autocomplete MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui

I got this PHP code:

```
// connect to mysql
require_once('includes/connect.php');
// include config
include('includes/config.php');

$nameser = $_GET['term'];

$search = Array();
$names = '';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM customers WHERE name LIKE '%".$nameser."%'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    $names = json_encode($row['name']);

echo $names;
```

But the output is not formatted right, so the autocomplete script cannot figure out what it should do with it.

Also, this example only outputs 1 entry, but there should be far more than that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the correct code:

```
$names = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  $names[] = $row['name'];

echo json_encode($names);
```

And as `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, consider using [`mysqli`](http://php.net/mysqli) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/pdo).

Comment: It doesn't work quite as expected - I get some of the output correct, but some of results just show up as null.

Comment: Also - how much of a job would it be to rewrite it to use mysqli?

Comment: For the `NULL`, I don't know for sure about the problem. Perhaps some of the values in `customer.name` are `NULL`? Converting your code from `mysql_*` to `mysqli` should not be too difficult.

Comment: Doing the query in phpmyadmin returns no rows with the value NULL - they do however contain special danish characters (Æ,Ø,Å)

Comment: Alright, fixed that part with a htmlentities.
Now I just got the problem that in my search box, Ø for example shows up as &Oslash; and not Ø.

Comment: any idea about my last comment?

Comment: I think you should remove the `htmlentities` and add this meta tag `<meta charset="utf-8" />` in your HTML.

Comment: I actually got it fixed with help from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488016/using-html-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete)