# Show multiple records on autocomplete

Tags: asp.net, sql, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I have a ASP.NET textbox autocomplete with JQuery, is working perfectly, i type part of the person name and displays the list with all the possible options, but now i want that when i search the name shows me on the list of results the email address next to the name, the names and emails are on a SQL database, i want that when i type John i get the list with

John Andrews John@email.com

John Smith Smith@email.com

And so on... this is the code:

```
  <%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Search_CS" %>
    using System;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Text;

    public class Search_CS : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        string prefixText = context.Request.QueryString["q"];
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager
                    .ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from directory where name like @SearchText + '%'";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText);
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        sb.Append(sdr["name"])
                            .Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
                context.Response.Write(sb.ToString()); 
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: if the email is in the same record just concatenate it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using html in jQuery UI autocomplete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488016/using-html-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when your adding name to your string builder, also add the email.. this code should work

```
while (sdr.Read())
{
    sb.Append(sdr["name"] + " " + sdr['email']).Append(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

or

```
while (sdr.Read())
{
    sb.Append(sdr["name"])
    sb.Append(" ") //space between name and email
    sb.Append(sdr['email'])
    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: Thanks yooou!!!! :D i could make it work!! at first i couldn't but i realized that on the email you used single ' ', and i was using " " doubles, now is working perfectly!!

Comment: Sorry about that, please don't forget to vote for my answer. Good luck with the rest of your project

Answer (score 1):

jQuery autocomplete allows you to display two fields.
For this you should use the jsonp datasource:

Take a look here at this [demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp).

To get your json data, you will have to change your IHttpHandler to output json

For this you will need to create a list of objects, and serialize it to json using the JavaScriptSerializer.

eg:

```
//myList = your list of objects with name and email.
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string jsonString = serializer.Serialize(myList);
```