# Jquery Autocomplete Menu Item Text Alignment/Padding/ Justified

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css

I have `JQuery UI AutoComplete` to a normal textbox displays few **Item-Name** with its **Item-Code.**

 I'm separating **Item-name & Item-Code** by `Pipe-Character " | "` - as shown below in the Image.

Now, the alignment / column alignment of each Item/string varies according to its length. Say one string is large and another short, so menu looks like **zig-zag**
I'm trying it to display the `MenuItem` string as `JUSTIFIED` or `EQUAL` length / alignment.

What `CSS` changes I have to make in order to accomplish this ?

Thank you :-)

[image]

Comment: Post some codes too so that we can advice something :), thank you for posting image for better understanding of requirement. :)

Comment: @MarmiK its normal `JQuery` Code
                    `$('#txtDeptCode').autocomplete({
                        source: data.Response,
                        minLength: 0
                        });`

Comment: IN which tag you are inserting the data?, add class to that tag and add css formatting to that tag. else create one more function to split('|'); using PIPE, and then assign them individually. <span style="width:150px;">name</span>|code  ------ or something like this..

Comment: Done MarmiK.. I found solution!!!
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is My Code---

```
        $.ajax({
            url: 'SomeController/someAction',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {},
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var x;
                $('#txtDeptCode').autocomplete({
                    source: data.Response,
                    minLength: 0,
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        x = ui.item.value;
                        event.preventDefault();
                        x = x.split('|');
                        $(this).val(x[1].split(' ')[1]);
                    }
                }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function rdrItem(ul, item) {
                    return $("<li></li>").data("item.ui-autocomplete", item).append("<a><div style='width:100%;'><div style='width:70%; float:left;'>" + item.value.split('|')[0] + " </div><div style='width:30%; float:right;'> </div><div>(" + item.value.split('|')[1] + ")</div></div></a>").appendTo(ul);
                };
```

And here is the output:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could for example extend the autocomplete a bit so that it renders HTML for each item. Then you could style these HTML elements how you like it. You may refer to this for an example on how to render HTML inside each item: [Using HTML in jQuery UI autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488016/using-html-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete)

Comment: Thanks reinder.. I extended it and made it render HTML for each.