# My autocomplete results are appearing with html tags

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

When I start writing on my input, my results appear with html tags, for example, if I search for "t" I get:  `Title<p><span>Content</span></p>`. And I want Title Content, without no html tags.

**This is my php:**

```
$search = isset($_GET['term']) ? $_GET['term'] : "";
$pdo = conecting();
$read = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * from articles WHERE title LIKE ?");   
$read ->bindValue(1, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$read ->execute();

$data = array();

while($res = $read ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
     $data[] = $res['title'].'-'.$res['content'];
  }
echo json_encode($data);
```

**This is my jQuery to start autocomplete:**

```
$('.j_autocomplete').autocomplete({

        source: 'http://localhost/project/tpl/search.php'
        select: function(event, ui){
            var get= ui.item.value; 
            returndata(get);
        },
        change: function(data)
        {
            returndata($(this).val());
        }
    });
```

Do you know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this way:

Add this code after autocomplete initialization:

```
.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
     return $("<li></li>")
         .data("item.autocomplete", item)
         .append("<a>" + item + "</a>")
         .appendTo(ul);
 };
```

Like this:

```
$('.j_autocomplete').autocomplete({

    source: 'http://localhost/project/tpl/search.php'
    select: function(event, ui){
        var get= ui.item.value; 
        returndata(get);
    },
    change: function(data)
    {
        returndata($(this).val());
    }
}).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
     return $("<li></li>")
         .data("item.autocomplete", item)
         .append("<a>" + item + "</a>")
         .appendTo(ul);
 };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ragnar. But with that Im with more strange chars like this: Title&content; more content-&morecontent;p&gt;&lt;span&gt;more content&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;

Comment: Yes my response is this: <li>Title <p><span>Here I have my content;&still have content;more content&nbsp;</span><strong>more content;more content</strong><span>&nbsp;que:</span><br /><span>Na pr&oacute;xima&nbsp;</span><strong>4&ordf;feira (dia 30), a partir das 13:30h</strong><span>, n&atilde;o haver&aacute; mor econtent &nbsp;</span><strong>more content &ordm; content </strong><span>. Content &ccedil;&atilde; more contet & content; 17h, content for Schools.</span><br /><span>content&nbsp;</span></p></li>

Comment: Thanks Ragnar for your help, but with your method autocomplete its not working :/

Comment: @OzzC take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488016/using-html-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete

Comment: Thank you for your attention Ragnar, but now I found a problem, I think problem its not about autocomplete. Because Im using tinymce plugin to my write my content text when I insert news, and text that I write in tinymce is saved in database with html tags! So problem must be in tinymce and not really on autocomplete! Do you know how to solve this in tinymce?

Comment: No, i don't know how to solve that problem with tinyMCE, i think that it's a codification problem. Have you tried setting header encoding to utf8?

Comment: Yes Ragnar, I have it on my header!